# Running unix process in background from php

Tags: php, shell, unix

If I run this unix command directly in shell:

```
$ sleep 100 &
```

sleep runs in the background as expected, and I can continue working in the command line.

but trying the same thing with shell_exec() and php I get different results.

```
<?php

  $sleep = $argv[1];
  $shell="sleep " . $sleep . " &";
  shell_exec($shell);

?>
```

when executing `php sleep.php 100` the command line hangs and wont accept any more commands until sleep finishes. I am not sure whether this is a nuance I am missing with `shell_exec()` / `$argv` of php or with the unix shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shell_exec` function is trying to capture the output of the command, which it can't do while simultaneously continuing processing. In fact, if you look at the php source code, the php `shell_exec` function does a `popen` C call, which does a `wait` syscall on the command. `wait` guarantees that the subprocess doesn't return until the child has exited.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the source code?

Comment: I just got it from a [mirror on github](https://github.com/php/php-src.git). Start [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/exec.c#L436)