# nohup ignored when ran through shell_exec

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface, nohup

When ran through *php*'s shell_exec, following code does not respect *nohup*:

```
root@N76 ~
$ php -r "echo exec('nohup sleep 5 > NUL 2>&1 &');"
(5 seconds later)
root@N76 ~
```

When executed in terminal/command line, it works as expected:

```
root@N76 ~
$ nohup sleep 5 > NUL 2>&1 &
[1] 12176
root@N76 ~
```

Is this expected behavior for POSIX like environment on Windows, or I'm doing something wrong (except running this on Windows)?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144869/running-unix-process-in-background-from-php/19145020#19145020

Comment: @kojiro yes and no, I forgot to mention I've tried opening process with various function like exec, shell_exec, popen, system, etc.

Comment: Did you read the PHP source code for those functions to see if any of them *doesn't* `waitpid`?

Comment: @kojiro haven't to be honest, but it works as expected on Linux. Question is a bit vague there is no guarantee it'll work on Windows, altough if there is a "solution", it would be nice to hear it. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused by the question because Windows doesn't *have* POSIX-like behavior.

Comment: Which Windows version? The POSIX like on Windows differs based on versions... .

Comment: To fork into background, for unix I use `$cmd >/dev/null &` and for windows I use psexec like `psexec /accepteula -d $cmd >%TEMP%\cmd.log 2>&1`